# Bootstrap nav-tabs not working when published

Tags: visual-studio, bootstrap-4, tabs, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Intranet Blazor server app. I've added Bootstrap nav-tabs which work as expected launching the Blazor project in Visual Studio. However, the tabs do not work when published to the IIS server. All other Bootstrap classes appear to be working ok.

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-1" target="_self" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-1" aria-selected="true">General Details</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-2" target="_self" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-2" aria-selected="false">Stationery</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-3" target="_self" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-3" aria-selected="false">Final Details</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Some text</div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-2-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-3-tab">...</div>

</div>

@*Stationery shows ... run from visual studio, but goes to the homepage displaying /#nav-2 in the address bar*@
```